# Query linq me trae datos inconsistentes

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2017

Hola trabajo EF code first, SQL Server 2014 Express Edition

Tengo la siguiente consulta linq

```
var result = from po in context.ProductoOrdenes
                         join p in context.Productos on po.ProductoId equals p.ProductoId
                         join pre in context.Presentaciones on po.PresentacionId equals pre.PresentacionId
                         join a in context.Almacenes on po.AlmacenId equals a.AlmacenId
                         join oi in context.OrdenInventarios on po.OrdenInventarioId equals oi.OrdenInventarioId
                         where
                         oi.EstadoOrden == EstadoOrden.Aprobado
                         &&
                         (filter.HasNumberOrder && oi.NumeroOrden.Contains(filter.NumeroOrden))
                         ||
                         (filter.HasFechaEmisionDesde && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oi.Fecha) >= filter.FechaEmisionDesde)
                         &&
                         (filter.HasFechaEmisionHasta && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oi.Fecha) <= filter.FechaEmisionHasta)
                         select
                         new ProductoOrdenInventarioExtend()
                         {
                             Id = po.ProductoOrdenId,
                             NumeroOrden = oi.NumeroOrden,
                             NombreProducto = p.Nombre,
                             PresentacionId = po.PresentacionId,
                             NombrePresentacion = pre.Nombre,
                             AlmacenId = po.AlmacenId,
                             NombreAlmacen = a.Nombre,
                             Cantidad = po.Cantidad,
                             TipoOperacion = po.TipoOperacion
                         };
            return result.ToList();
```

Cuando comento el filtro de fechas me trae los datos que necesito, cuando comento el filtro de NumeroOrden y dejo solo fechas me trae los datos que necesito.

> El problema es cuando envió toda la consulta cuando filtro por fechas
>   me trae datos inconsistentes por que solo estoy pidiendo EstadoOrden =
>   Aprobado y me trae de todos los estados. ¿Que puede estar mal?

SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductoOrdenId] AS [ProductoOrdenId], 
[Extent5].[NumeroOrden] AS [NumeroOrden], 
[Extent2].[Nombre] AS [Nombre], 
[Extent1].[PresentacionId] AS [PresentacionId], 
[Extent3].[Nombre] AS [Nombre1], 
[Extent1].[AlmacenId] AS [AlmacenId], 
[Extent4].[Nombre] AS [Nombre2], 
[Extent1].[Cantidad] AS [Cantidad], 
[Extent1].[TipoOperacion] AS [TipoOperacion]
FROM     [dbo].[ProductoOrdenes] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Productos] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProductoId] = [Extent2].[ProductoId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Presentaciones] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[PresentacionId] = [Extent3].[PresentacionId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Almacenes] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[AlmacenId] = [Extent4].[AlmacenId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrdenInventarios] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[OrdenInventarioId] = [Extent5].[OrdenInventarioId]
WHERE ((2 = [Extent5].[EstadoOrden]) 
AND (@p__linq__0 = 1) OR ([Extent5].[NumeroOrden] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE ''~'')) 
OR ((@p__linq__2 = 1) AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent5].[Fecha], 102) ,  102)) >= @p__linq__3) 
    AND (@p__linq__4 = 1) AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent5].[Fecha], 102) ,  102)) <= @p__linq__5))',
N'@p__linq__0 bit,
@p__linq__1 varchar(8000),
@p__linq__2 bit,
@p__linq__3 datetime2(7),
@p__linq__4 bit,
@p__linq__5 datetime2(7)',
@p__linq__0=0,
@p__linq__1='%%',
@p__linq__2=1,
@p__linq__3='2020-02-04 00:00:00',
@p__linq__4=1,
@p__linq__5='2020-02-21 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no seria asi?

```
oi.EstadoOrden == EstadoOrden.Aprobado
                         &&
                         ((filter.HasNumberOrder && oi.NumeroOrden.Contains(filter.NumeroOrden))
                         ||
                         ((filter.HasFechaEmisionDesde && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oi.Fecha) >= filter.FechaEmisionDesde)
                         &&
                         (filter.HasFechaEmisionHasta && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oi.Fecha) <= filter.FechaEmisionHasta)))
```

Comment: Es así como lo tengo

Comment: Le agregue un parentesis luego del oi.EstadoOrden == EstadoOrden.Aprobado && y otro que engloba las fechas. Asi como lo tenes, se fija aprobado Y el numero de orden o fechaemision desde Y fecha emision hasta

Comment: Gonzalo, funciona ¿que hace los paréntesis?

Comment: En realidad es el orden que evalua. Supuse que las fechas querias evaluarlas en conjunto para que se cumpla que esten en un rango, y por eso la englobe en un parentesis. Y lo mismo el nro de orden O las fechas. De la forma que lo pusiste vos, queda como te comente en la resp anterior. Si no fui muy claro buscate info de orden de evaluacion de booleanos. Suerte

Comment: Me quedo claro Gonzalo, gracias por la explicación.